# Connections drop randomly on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, networking, lan

my connections (wan/internet and LAN) drop randomly. I get server timeout when attempt to load a webpage and my Windows Live messenger drops out of connection.

This has happened several times; when it does happen I try to access my router's webpage (http://192.168.2.15) and it won't load, so this isn't a specific wan/internet problem, its most likely Windows 7.

I am not using DHCP, I enter in the IP/subnetmask and default gateway manually. This is because the LAN is complicated (two internets/gateways, two routers). The setup is flawless. (All DHCP turned off, all computers on one router and the second router pluged into the main router as a slave) then just switch default gateway to switch internet provider.

No other computer has this problem. Windows 7 diagnostics / connection area doesn't show any disconnection when it happens.

What could this be?

Comment: "LAN is complicated ... (the) setup is flawless"

Comment: Have you tried another OS on the box? What's to say it's not a dud NIC? Why is it "likely Windows 7"?

Comment: Have check the driver for the NIC? Did it just update to a new driver? If so try to roll it back to the last working driver, if not check for a update.